# Facebook app in Page Tab not visible to not logged in users (content not available)

Tags: facebook

I tried to create my first facebook app. It is a simple countdown to a specific date (does not require user to log in, or anything). It is added as a Page Tab on my page. The problem is, that while the page tab is visible to everyone, the app itself is visible only to logged in users. When I log out, I get "content is not available" message after clicking on the tab.

When I go to "Canvas page"`https://apps.facebook.com/xxx`, I can view it even if I am not logged in.

I have no restrictions in the app settings, and the app is hosted on SSL server.

Can the problem be in the code of the application? I tried both - using the init `<script>` proposed in facebook documentation and removing it, doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Only found a few people complaining and saw that this wasn't working anywhere else either. I knew it was working a few months ago.

Anyway: Today it suddenly started working again. There's probably nothing wrong with you app. (Though age and country restrictions can still lock it down.)

Comment: You are right! It started to work. Thanks for your answer.